# How works site search in attachments

Tags: google-apps-script

When I apply `site.search('string')` it doesn't return results from attachments. Does this method only apply to page content and not attachments?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this returns only those pages which have a matching string text. This will not search in hosted attachments.
To search for matches with attachment names, you may iterate over the names of attachments in each page and return page which has matching attachment name.